# Android multiple Button color changes

Tags: android

So, I have this problem, I'm trying to make a Button change it´s color, and the color of the other buttons that sorround it when i click on it, and it needs to stay like that, until some one clicks on it again, or until some on clicks on a button that sorrounds it. The picture makes it easier to understand. [UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krBAS.jpg)

so eg. when you click number 6, numbers 2,6,7,5,10 need to change its color to red, and, when you click on it again, they need to change it's color back to green.
  So, I did this:

```
 Button[] btns = new Button[16]; //colocando 16 botões nele

    btns[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btns[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btns[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    btns[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

    btns[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    btns[5] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    btns[6] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    btns[7] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);

    btns[8] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
    btns[9] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);
    btns[10] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button11);
    btns[11] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button12);

    btns[12] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button13);
    btns[13] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button14);
    btns[14] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button15);
    btns[15] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button16);
```

And now I'm a bit lost. I've built the game logic already on paper, the problem is, I don't know how to change the color of multiple buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say you have the logic already, I guess you only need to be shown how to change the background color of the appropriate buttons. In this case, I'd have a method that takes an array of `Button` objects and the color to set them to:

```
private void changeColorOfTheseButtons(Button[] buttons, int color){
  for(int x=0; x < buttons.length; x++){
     //change its color
     buttons[x].setBackgroundColor(color);
   }
}
```

Then this is how you call the method above with a color (assuming you already have the list of buttons whose color you want to change):

```
...
changeColorOfTheseButtons(arrayOfButtonsToChange, Color.RED);
```

using color RED as example above - but you can use any color in `Color.*`

I hope this gives you some ideas.

Comment: I am glad this helped you. Please vote the answer if you found it useful. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a 2D array instead of a 1d array to do this. Then the logic is easy just get the buttons surrounding spot i,j would be (i-1,j-1),(i-1,j),(i-1,j+1), etc. You should easily be able to do this and add the appropriate logic for corner cases(aka buttons on the corners/edges).

Comment: Yes, It's also an idea, but should I use an onClick method to change the colors ?

Comment: you should use some sort of custom on click method that you can pass the indexes of the button to (i,j). Attach that to each button and then using that to get all the necessary buttons in the onclick method and change their color. I haven't done android development in about a year but I believe you should be able to do something like that fairly easily

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd just set up the logic. Your picture would be easier to set up this structure if you started with 0 to 15 as well.

if you have a 4x4 grid as you show then which ever one is clicked would have:

- x = number of button clicked.
- n1 = x - 4
- n2 = x + 4
- n3 = x + 1
- n4 = x - 1

Will all be Changed UNLESS they aren't greater than 0 or less than 16 ( 0 < n < 16) and if for just (x + 1) and (x - 1) as follows:

- n3 % 4  == 0
- n4 % 4  == 3
- The 3 value comes from (4 - 1)

This algorithm could be extended to any x by x square grid by replacing the 4's with the x value as well.

Then if n3 or n4  don't  get changed on the grid if they don't meet these requirements.

Thus have a function that accepts an int representing the number of the box clicked (x) and the btn grid itself, then apply this logic with x, n1, n2, n3, and n4 on the buttons clicked.

If those qualities above are met run another check for color and based off current color change it to the other.