# How do I efficiently change a property to multiple views/buttons in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, view, mobile-development

I am getting started on Android development and I've had trouble finding answers since I may not know how to word things properly. What I am trying to do is setting all buttons invisible once I click on any button. The easy way out of it is this:

```
Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
Button button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
Button button4 = findViewById(R.id.button4);

setInvisible(button1);
setInvisible(button2);
setInvisible(button3);
setInvisible(button4);
```

However I feel like this goes against the DRY principle of programming. I mean what if there were 100 buttons?

After doing some thinking, I imagine I can use a loop and have i be the place holder for the numbers of each button. That way it would loop through every single one. However I am not sure on what methods to use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android multiple Button color changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37712534/android-multiple-button-color-changes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private int[] btnIds = new int[]{R.id.button1, R.id.button2, R.id.button3, R.id.button4};
    private List<Button> buttonList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_button_group);

        for(int i = 0; i < btn.length; i++){
            buttonList.add(findViewById(btnIds[i])); 
            buttonList.get(i).setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Either check for button ids or simply:
        for (Button button : buttonList) {
            button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);//or View.GONE
        }
    }
}
```